# Oracle picks wrong index when joining table

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, query-performance

I have a long query, but similar to the short version here:

```
select * from table_a a

left join table_b b on

b.id = a.id and
b.name = 'CONSTANT';
```

There are 2 indexes on `table_b` for both `id` and `name`, `idx_id` has fewer duplicates and `idx_name` has a lot of duplicates. This is quite a large table (20M+ records). And the `join` is taking 10min+.

A simple explain plan shows a lot of memory uses on the join part, and it shows it uses the index for `name` as opposed to `id`.

How to solve this issue? How to force using the `idx_id` index?

I was thinking of putting `b.name='CONSTANT'` to where clause, but this is a left join and where will remove all the record that exists in table_a.

---

Updated explain plan. Sorry cannot paste the whole plan.

Explain plan with `b.name='CONSTANT'`:

[image: Wrong index]

Explain plan when commenting `b.name` clause:

[image]

Comment: *A simple explain plan shows a lot of memory uses on the join part, and it shows it uses the index for name as opposed to id.* So, where is the explain plan?

Comment: Are your statistics up to date on both tables?

Comment: Without the whole plan, this is a waste of time.

Answer (score 0):

Add an optimizer hint to your query.

Without knowing your 'long' query, it's difficult to know if Oracle is using the wrong one, or if your interpretation that indexb < indexa so therefore must be quicker for query z is correct.

To add a hint the syntax is

```
select /*+ index(table_name index_name) */ * from ....;
```

Answer (score 0):

What is the size of TABLE_A relative to TABLE_B?  It wouldn't make sense to use the ID index unless TABLE_A had significantly less rows than TABLE_B.

Index range scans are generally only useful when they access a small percentage of the rows in a table.  Oracle reads the index one-block-at-a-time, and then still has to pull the relevant row from the table.  If the index isn't very selective, that process can be slower than a multi-block full table scan.

Also, it might help if you can post the full explain plan using this text format:

```
explain plan for select ... ;
select * from table(dbms_xplan.display);
```